# Numeration of groups in regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I am learning regular expressions in Python but couldn't find out what is numeration in `.group()` based on.

Here is my code:

```
import re
string = 'suzi sabin joe brandon josh'
print(re.search(r'^.*\b(suzi|sabin|joe|brandon|josh)\b.*$', string).group(0))
# output : suzi sabin joe brandon josh

print(re.search(r'^.*\b(suzi|sabin|joe|brandon|josh)\b.*$', string).group(1))
# output : josh
```

I am wondering

- Why is there only group(1) and not group(1-5)?
- Why was josh classified into group(1)?

I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: Use `(` and `)` to capture groups, and there was only one. `josh` was the last match so it's grouped  by itself lastly.

Comment: Simply and helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `group(0)`, you get the whole matched text, which is the whole string, since your pattern matches from the beginning of the string to the end.

While the regex *matches* everything, it only *captures* one name (in group 1 because regex counts from 1 for historical reasons). Because the first `.*` is greedy (it tries to match as much text as possible), it gobbles up the earlier names, and the captured name is the last one, `"josh"` (and the last `.*` matches an empty string). The captured name is what you get when you call `group(1)`.

If you want to separately capture each name, you'll need to do things differently. Probably something like this would work:

```
print(re.findall(r'\b(suzi|sabin|joe|brandon|josh)\b', string))
```

This will print the list `['suzi', 'sabin', 'joe', 'brandon', 'josh']`. Each name will appear in the output in the same order it appears in the input string, which need not be the same order they were in the pattern. This might not do exactly what you want though, since it will skip over any text that isn't one of the names you're looking for (rather than failing to match anything).